# Get distinct email id from contact list

Tags: android

I have a contact list with multiple names having the same email Ids.How can I modify the below code so that I get only names with distinct email id.

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails(){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                new String[]{id}, null); 
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                    //to get the contact names
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.add(name);
                    }
                } 
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a cursor in sqlite to get the distinct values, the useage of true gives the distinct values only

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.query(true,"window",new String[]{"MediaType","_id",TAG_DATA_OR_LOCATION}, null, null,"DataOrLocation", null, null, null);
```

**public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)**

Comment: I want to access the contact list(I prefer contentResolver) I dont think sqliteDB will work on phone's contact list.Correct me if am wrong